# hardware not working while on battery

Tags: usb, bluetooth, hardware, camera, wifi-hardware-switch

I am a complete beginner to linux.

My first distro is Ubuntu and I have installed it on my laptop Asus Vivobook 15 x512da.

My problem is that when I am using the laptop on battery, laptop's bluetooth, camera usb ports for usb keyboard and mouse won't work, but for pendrives it works.

When I use the laptop *while charging* all these things work, but to make that work on charging I have to reboot the laptop.

Then it only starts, and when I turn off the charging it works untill the laptop screen is on. When the laptop turns down laptop lid it again stops working.

And one more thing, can you also suggest me how to learn linux so that I can use it for my laptop in day to day life.

Comment: Welcome! I edited the question, but there are some parts that are unclear to me. Can you read my editing and tell me if I understood you correctly?

Comment: *"And one more thing, can you also suggest me how to learn linux so that I can use it for my laptop in day to day life."* This is too broad a scope and not what AskUbuntu is meant for. When you have *specific* problems related to Ubuntu use, you can post a question again here. Google "starting with ubuntu" and you will get a bunch of videos and articles to getting started with Ubuntu and Linux in general.